# TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable, while iterating through 2D Array

Tags: python, python-3.x, multidimensional-array

There is a function that accepts 2D_INTEGER_ARRAY students_marks as parameter.
I have to calculate grade for all students given in the list, store into the list, and return it. Steps to calculate the grade for students: Iterate each student calculate the average score, and find the grade based on the average of a student Store the grade for each student into a list, and return it.
Whenever I try to iterate through the 2D array it shows me the error.
my code :

```
def calculateGrade(students_marks):

l=[]
k=[]
for i in students_marks:
    for j in i:
        avg=sum(j)/len(i)
        l.append(avg)
        
for i in range(l+1):
    
    if i>=90:
        k.append("A+")
    elif i in range(80,90):
        k.append("A")
    elif i in range(70,80):
        k.append("B") 
    elif i in range(60,70):
        k.append("C")
    elif i in range(50,60):
        k.append("D")                 
    elif i<50:
        k.append("F")
return k                
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

students_marks_rows = int(input().strip())
students_marks_columns = int(input().strip())

students_marks = []

for _ in range(students_marks_rows):
    students_marks.append(list(map(int, input().rstrip().split())))

result = calculateGrade(students_marks)

fptr.write('\n'.join(result))
fptr.write('\n')

fptr.close()
```

My Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "Solution.py", line 56, in <module>

    result = calculateGrade(students_marks)

  File "Solution.py", line 24, in calculateGrade

    avg=sum(j)/len(i)

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: Looking at the traceback, it seems the error is originating from your variable j (trying to sum over an int which is indeed not an iterable)

Comment: @LucBertin but without j I cant enter in i. Suggest me some idea how to approach the elements in i.

Answer (score -1):

```py
def calculateGrade(students_marks):
    r = []
    
    for  i in range(len(students_marks)):
        avg= int(sum(students_marks[i])/students_marks_columns)
        if avg >= 90:
            r.append('A+')
        elif avg in range(80,90):
            r.append('A')
        elif avg in range(70,80):
            r.append('B')
        elif avg in range(60,70):
            r.append('C')
        elif avg in range(50,60):
            r.append('D')
        else:
            r.append('F')
        
    return r
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  It's best if in addition to a solution you describe what the solution does and why it answers the question.